# What should I use instead of deprecated GKLeaderboardViewController in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

ive updated my app for IOS 7 and game center has a few things deprecated such as loading and dismissing the leaderboard and achievements how can i fix them it says GKLeaderboardViewController is deprecated

```
- (IBAction)LeaderBoardsButton:(id)sender {
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID2);
}
}

- (IBAction)AchievementsButton:(id)sender {
GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController
                                              alloc] init];
if (achievements != nil)
{
    achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:achievements animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
}

- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController
                                        *)viewController
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID2);
}
}
```

i am reporting the score like this

```
- (IBAction)ShareScore:(id)sender {
[self.gameCenterManager reportScore: counter forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];

GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL)
{
    leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

iOS 7 combines the leaderboards, achievements, etc. controllers together into the [`GKGameCenterViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) class. You use the [`viewState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKGameCenterViewController/viewState) parameter to control which view you want displayed.

You'll want to do something like this to present/dismiss the leaderboards:

```
- (void) presentLeaderboards {
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*) gameCenterViewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Similarly, for presenting achievements, you can do this:

```
- (void) presentAchievements {
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Reporting score would look something like this:

```
- (void) reportHighScore:(NSInteger) highScore forLeaderboardId:(NSString*) leaderboardId {
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
        GKScore* score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:leaderboardId];
        score.value = highScore;
        [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: hi greg that worked perfect i edited the question as i missed out the reporting score section how would i tackle that?

Comment: how would i trigger the void statement as i want it triggered when the game ends and when they submit there score

Comment: Do you mean how do you call the reportHighScore:forLeaderboardId: method? That would be analogous to this line that you wrote above: [self.gameCenterManager reportScore: counter forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];. Instead you would do something like [self reportHighScore:counter forLeaderboardId:self.currentLeaderBoard];.

Comment: you sir are a beautiful man i applaud you and send you a virtual Hi5

Comment: @Greg what is Highscore

Comment: whoops like in score.value = Highscore;

Comment: It's the first parameter of the reportHighScore:forLeaderboardId: method in my example. The documentation for GKScore's value property is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKScore/value